# Debug session stopping after minimizing app on device ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am using Xcode 10.3 and running my iOS application on my iPhone, the debug session starts, but when I minimize the application by pressing home button, the debug session stops, but I still want to see the session.

I've tried on devices and simulators but same result. My colleagues are using Xcode with a version older than mine by 2 i think. They run their app and when they minimize it, the debug session stays running.

Comment: Have you get solution'?

Comment: No still the same

Comment: Does lldb say 'Finished running AppName on DeviceName' in the activity window?  The debugger doesn't control what happens to your app when it goes into the background, it is just responding to that.  It's up to iOS to decide what to do when an app is backgrounded.  So if the app really is exiting, the question you need to answer is why is your app killed going into the background whereas other apps are not...